# What does the notation $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, localization

While I was studying on paper I saw the notation $R=\mathbb{Z_{(2)}}×\mathbb{Z}$, so what does the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ mean?

Comment: I would have thought the localisation of ${\mathbb Z}$ at the prime $2$: the subring of $\mathbb Q$ with elements "having no $2$'s dividing the denominator."

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a citation to the paper you are reading?

Comment: When parens are *absent*, e.g. $\mathbb Z_2$ it could mean either $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z$ localized at $(2)$. But with $(2)$ it is highly suggestive of the latter notation $\mathbb Z_P$ for localization at a prime ideal.  I don't think I've ever seen anyone write $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ for $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ could also mean the ring of 2-adic integers.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner While $\,\Bbb Z_2\,$ can denote either a quotient or localization, I've never seen $\,\Bbb Z_{(2)}\,$ used for the quotient - only the localization. Where did you see that?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Great, I removed my prior comment (and soon this one)

Answer (score 4):

It most probably means the [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) of the ring $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(2)=2\mathbb Z$.

A concrete realization of this localization is the set of all rational numbers with odd denominator.